# GTK WebAssembly support in the near future?

Tags: qt, gtk, gtk3, webassembly

Do you have any information about GTK WebAssembly support in the near future? QT has announced this week the WebAssembly support, and provided a few impressive online demo. I would like to stick with GTK, I feel it more intuitive for me, but from a technology perspective, WebAssembly support is something to consider.

Comment: Isn't Webassembly supported in GTK trough WebKit?

Comment: I mean, to be able to run your gtk app in browser, and render it there.

Comment: Could you move your reply into an answer? I would like to accept it. Your answer is the solution to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think [Broadway](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-broadway.html) uses WebAssembly under the hood, but it accomplishes what you asked in your "run your gtk app in browser" comment.